# pgRouting on RHEL6: issues with driving distance library

Tags: pgrouting, elgis

I installed pgrouting on RHEL6 via yum and the ELGIS 6 repo (the only place where I could find pgrouting for RHEL6).

The problem is that the `librouting_dd.so` library (for driving distance) is missing. In other words, I have `librouting.so`, `librouting_tsp.so`, but *not* `librouting_dd.so`. *Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it?* I've included the yum output below.

I also tried compiling pgrouting from source (with the `-DWITH_DD=ON` flag so librouting_dd.so would be built) but this resulted in a waterfall of dependency issues (e.g., it needs CGAL-devel, which in turn needs things like lapack-devel and blas-devel which aren't installing because of other dependency issues, etc., etc.).

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
# yum install pgrouting
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or RHN Satellite.
elgis                                                                                                                                                                                    | 3.0 kB     00:00     
elgis-plus                                                                                                                                                                               | 1.3 kB     00:00     
elgis-source                                                                                                                                                                             | 3.0 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pgrouting.x86_64 0:1.05-1_0.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

============================================================================================
 Package         Arch      Version         Repository                      Size
============================================================================================
Installing:
 pgrouting      x86_64     1.05-1_0.el6    elgis                            66 k

Transaction Summary
============================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 66 k
Installed size: 226 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
pgrouting-1.05-1_0.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                                                                        |  66 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : pgrouting-1.05-1_0.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                1/1 
  Verifying  : pgrouting-1.05-1_0.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                                                1/1 

Installed:
  pgrouting.x86_64 0:1.05-1_0.el6                                                                                                                                                                               

Complete!
[root@vm1 yum.repos.d]# rpm -sql pgrouting
normal        /usr/lib64/pgsql/librouting.so
normal        /usr/lib64/pgsql/librouting_tsp.so
normal        /usr/share/doc/pgrouting-1.05
normal        /usr/share/doc/pgrouting-1.05/README.routing
normal        /usr/share/postlbs
normal        /usr/share/postlbs/matching.sql
normal        /usr/share/postlbs/routing_core.sql
normal        /usr/share/postlbs/routing_core_wrappers.sql
normal        /usr/share/postlbs/routing_topology.sql
normal        /usr/share/postlbs/routing_tsp.sql
normal        /usr/share/postlbs/routing_tsp_wrappers.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [this](http://people.planetpostgresql.org/devrim/index.php?/archives/73-pgRouting-RPM-package-was-sponsored,-and-it-is-now-available!.html) forum post, Devrim Gunduz contributed a [pgRouting package for RHEL6](http://yum.postgresql.org/9.2/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/repoview/pgrouting_92.html) in November 2012 which includes driving distance. It can be downloaded from the [postgres YUM repo](http://yum.postgresql.org/repopackages.php#pg92) (aka "pgdg92").

Specifically, my issue was that yum was only seeing the pgrouting package offered by another repository that I had installed (elgis). I needed configure yum ignore that pgrouting package so that it would see (and use) the one in pgdg92. In other words, I added the following line to my `elgis.repo` config file:

```
exclude=pgrouting*
```